# How to concatenate strings in a tuple?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

```
input:[("xyz",100),("tao",90),("quinee",100)]
```

when the **numbers are equal** the strings are to be concatenated into a single list.

```
 output:[(["xyz","quinee"],100),(["tao"],90)]
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can do that.

```
from itertools import groupby

def key(x): return x[1]

input=[("xyz",100),("tao",90),("quinee",100)]

output = [
    (list(string for string,index in group),index)
    for index,group in groupby(sorted(input, key=key, reverse=True), key=key)]

assert output ==  [(["xyz","quinee"],100),(["tao"],90)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [("xyz",100),("tao",90),("quinee",100)]

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    d[i[1]].append(i[0])

r = [(j, i) for i, j in d.items()]
print(r)
# [(['tao'], 90), (['xyz', 'quinee'], 100)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a defaultdict, that defaults its value to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def concat(lst):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in lst:
        d[v].append(k)
    return [(v, k) for k, v in d.items()]
```